# iOS with UICollectionView how to achieve this type of layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[image: CollectionView with left view Show]
[image: CollectionView with left view Hide]

**Requirement:**

- I should be able to scroll entire view if left view is visible or not (all components should scroll at a time if i scroll anywhere with in the view).
- By clicking on **show/hide left view button** button it should be able to hide or show left view.
- In cell (only cell not left view) there is a expand/collapse functionality (i can increase/decrease cell height)
- And If i change font size in device settings app, it should be effect here also(So supporting dynamic font size)

**What i have tried:**

I have tried with tableview, scroll view but no luck. Finally want to try with collection view, can any one please help me out how to proceed with collection view. And in future do we get any complications if we use collection view.

Comment: Should the left view stay in place as the cells scroll?

Comment: No, the entire view should scroll(HeaderView, LeftView, cells)

Comment: Can you share the type of views you are planning to use on the left side? So perhaps with a single table view, it could be achieved.

Comment: It sounds like you will need to make a custom UICollectionView layout.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan: Left View - contains multiple options in this case i am planning to use tableview, because it contains many options but disabling the scrolling(So that where ever i scroll it will scroll entire view)

Comment: try swrevealviecontroller

Comment: I think you should check out [SpreadSheet](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView)

Answer (score 1):

### Best Approach.

1. Your UI hierarchy should be like this.

> StackView
>
> > CollectionView
> >
> > TableView

**Note:** You can take both `CollectionView` or `TableView` but I prefer both different so that I don't need to put condition in delegates & datasource and I can manage easily. Choice is your's what you like to prefer.

[image]

2. Now your UI design looks like this

   - Green color button is used to show hide your left collectionview (you mentioned in your post).

[image]

3. Set your datas in `CollectionView` and `TableView` as per your requirement.
4. To toggle left menu, just use below one line code on greenButton action.

   ```
   @IBAction func btnToggle(_ sender: Any) {
       colView.isHidden = !colView.isHidden 
   }
   ```
5. For simple animation

   ```
   @IBAction func btnToggle(_ sender: Any) {
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {            
           self.colView.isHidden = !self.colView.isHidden
       }
   }
   ```

**Output:**

[image]

> Edit

You can take stackView in scrollview and turn off colview, tblView scrolling. Check below :

1. UI heirarchy

[image]

2. Additional code work

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       colView.isScrollEnabled = false
       tblView.isScrollEnabled = false

       colView.reloadData()
       tblView.reloadData()

       scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width,
                                       height:  max(colView.contentSize.height, tblView.contentSize.height))
       stackHeight.constant = scrollView.contentSize.height

   }
   ```

**Note :** It may cause some unexpected output (can be / can not be), so you need to take care of it.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: hmm your solution don't work for me, because with this approach scrolling is applicable to individual component. Please read my comment above

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but i think this is not efficient solution because if we disable the scrollview in individual components and providing all content size(In this case we are not using features of collectionview/tableview). Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBattula Both are individual components and both works separately, to make them work as a single unit you need to bind them with something.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is UICollectionView with custom layout. You can achieve the effect you need using this approach.

There is tone of tutorials how to implement own custom layout. 
[Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) is one of them

Comment: Does any one of tones of tutorials solve OP's issue?